# Infograph Date Complication - what ComplicationTemplate is this?

Tags: watchkit

I'm doing some development for the Infograph Complications.

I can't figure out what template the Date Complication is for the CLKComplicationFamilyGraphicBezel.

Can someone please tell me what Template this is?

Screenshot attached

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ClockKit doesn’t provide a “stacked text” complication template for this Complication Family as of watchOS 5.1, which seems like a strange omission.

It is likely the Date complication is either using some sort of private `GraphicCircularStackText` complication template, or using the public `CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage` and rendering the appropriate text as an image.